# What is the purpose of child in Consumer Provider Flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

I have a question about Consumer, of Provider package, in Flutter.
I don't understand the purpose of argument "child" in the builder of Consumer

```
Consumer<MyModel>(builder: (context, myModel, child) {
// doing stuff using myModel variable
});
```

I could not find any doc about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The child can be used as a part which does not rebuild when the provider value changes and the Consumer rebuilds.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final valueProvider = Provider<int>((ref) => 10);
final stateProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 20);

void main() => runApp(ProviderScope(child: const MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const title = 'Riverpod Test';
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(title: title),
    );
  }
}



class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Consumer(

          builder: (context, WidgetRef ref, child) {
            print(context);
            final value = ref.watch(valueProvider);
            final stateValue = ref.watch(stateProvider);

            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('$value, $stateValue'),
                Container(child: child),
                Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    print('$context child 2');
                    return Container(child: Text('Child 2'));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },

          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              print('$context child 1');
              return Text('Child 1');
            },
          ),

        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: Consumer(
        builder: (_, WidgetRef ref, __) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ref.read(stateProvider.state).state++;
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The child 2 is inside the Consumer widget and it rebuilds when you press + button. But child 1 never rebuilds

```
I/flutter (16579): Consumer(dirty, dependencies: [UncontrolledProviderScope], state: _ConsumerState#7620b)
I/flutter (16579): Builder(dirty) child 1
I/flutter (16579): Builder(dirty) child 2
Reloaded 1 of 614 libraries in 1,176ms (compile: 80 ms, reload: 686 ms, reassemble: 299 ms).
I/flutter (16579): Consumer(dirty, dependencies: [UncontrolledProviderScope], state: _ConsumerState#7620b)
I/flutter (16579): Builder(dirty) child 2
I/flutter (16579): Consumer(dirty, dependencies: [UncontrolledProviderScope], state: _ConsumerState#7620b)
I/flutter (16579): Builder(dirty) child 2
I/flutter (16579): Consumer(dirty, dependencies: [UncontrolledProviderScope], state: _ConsumerState#7620b)
I/flutter (16579): Builder(dirty) child 2
```

Comment: right and pointed answer

Answer (score 27):

The child is any widget that doesn't need the data inside of the provider, so when the data gets updated, they don't get re-created since they don't need the data, rather they are passed as a reference to the builder.

```
    Consumer(
       builder: (context, myModel, child) {
       // child will refer to the MaterialButton provided as the child argument in the 
       // Consumer named parameter,
       // doing stuff using myModel variable
       }
       child: MaterialButton( 
              child: Text("Do some action"), 
              onPressed: () {
              // do some actions
    },),);
```

Since the MaterialButton doesn't need the state of the provider, but its in the descendant tree, there is no need to re-render that, so it gets passed back to the builder, to save memory and increase performance

Comment: But, how this will layout on-screen ? will it be horizontal or vertical or more .... we are returning a widget to the builder and return a widget to the child so how flutter will layout them?

Comment: its optional , if you need it you display it, else you can omit the child

Comment: @ChinkySight i have the same question. I think the answer is that it first tries to use builder widget but if no builder widget is there, then it falls back to child?

Comment: @MobileMon It's not like that, as we know we can use Provider for both dependency injection and state management. If the `Consumer` is of type `ChangeNotifierProvider` and we don't a specific widget to rebuild when `notifyListener()` is called then we can we use the `child` property.

Comment: is this returing the same instance of a Material button from the cache?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass child widget in consumer. What ever widget you pass as a child will not rebuild when data is changed.

You can avoid unnecessary rebuild of widget using child.

Comment: But, how this will layout on-screen ? will it be horizontal or vertical or more .... we are returning a widget to the builder and return a widget to the child so how flutter will layout them?

Comment: you will get the same behaviour of child widget if you pasted code inside it self. @ChinkySight

Comment: Another question here: I have a widget tree which consists of `Scaffold`, `AppBar`, and a `Column`. The Column has three widgets: `Text`, `Future Builder`, `Flat Button`. I want to rebuild everything(**AppBar, Column ..**) when the state of the provider changes, except the **Future Builder(else it will perform unnecessary read).**

Comment: then you must wrap consumer above scaffold and assign future builder to child and use child where ever you want to use in your case between text and flat button.

Comment: Now I got it, how the child works thank you very much :D